# View session durations for reached goals

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I'm fighting with analytics to make this working.

I've settled a goal, and I would like to know the session duration for those who reach this goal.

Any ideas?

Comment: hope thest links works for you :
http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/hits-sessions-metrics-dimensions-web-analytics/

http://nadiaorenes.es/blog_en/2014/09/improve-metrics-increase-average-session-length/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a segment where you only select the people who have completed the goal.

Then you will be able to analyse how long people who complete the goal stay on the site, how many pages they view, where they are coming from.

Checkout this page from Google on creating segments:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en

or watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dD-j9dgWF98

Comment: Your welcome Niko. Segmentation will gives you insights!